# Google sign-in using Javascript API without triggering popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

I am using following code for users to be able to login using their Google account via Javascript API.

**HTML**

`<a id="gp_login" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:googleAuth()">Login using Google</a>`

**Javascript**

```
function gPOnLoad(){
     // G+ api loaded
     document.getElementById('gp_login').style.display = 'block';
}
function googleAuth() {
    gapi.auth.signIn({
        callback: gPSignInCallback,
        clientid: googleKey,
        cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
        requestvisibleactions: "http://schema.org/AddAction",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email"
    })
}

function gPSignInCallback(e) {
    if (e["status"]["signed_in"]) {
        gapi.client.load("plus", "v1", function() {
            if (e["access_token"]) {
                getProfile()
            } else if (e["error"]) {
                console.log("There was an error: " + e["error"])
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log("Sign-in state: " + e["error"])
    }
}

function getProfile() {
    var e = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        userId: "me"
    });
    e.execute(function(e) {
        if (e.error) {
            console.log(e.message);
            return
        } else if (e.id) {
            // save profile data
        }
    })
}(function() {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.type = "text/javascript";
    e.async = true;
    e.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=gPOnLoad";
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
})()
```

This code is working fine.
I want to use the above code (using Javascript) to login user from their Google account **without triggering a popup window**. Like, user clicks the login link, asked for app permissions in the same window/tab, user grants permission, user redirected back to the page where Google login link was, profile data is saved and user is logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Such functionality is not provided through Google API. You should stick with gapi.auth.signIn. I know just one way to make it work, but it's very hacky.**

gapi.auth.signIn opens authentication window. 
Save authentication window url in your app<sup>1</sup>.
Instead of calling gapi.auth.signIn, redirect user to that url.

To redirect successful authentication back to your website, add/modify redirect_url param in the url<sup>2</sup>. Keep in mind that redirect_uri must be registered in developers console.

Example:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&immediate=false&response_type=token**&redirect_uri=http://example.com**

This way google will redirect user back to your website. access_token is provided through GET params.

<sup>1</sup>If google changes their API this may break (since this method bypasses JS API and assumes that all those params in the url will be supported for ever).

<sup>2</sup>Redirect_url is introduced in [offline access flow documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer). I don't think this param was intended to work in any other cases.

**I strongly advise not to use this idea (since it bypasses JS API and uses undocumented functionality). Stick with gapi.auth.signIn.**

Comment: Note: It looks like Zendesk does something exactly like this, supported or no. (And, I'm glad they did because it clears up possible accounts confusion.) Hopefully the Google API will be upgraded soon with this feature.

Answer (score 22):

You can the use **ux_mode** parameter (options are *'redirect'* or *'popup'*) and set a **redirect_uri** if you want to redirect to a different page.

It's also necessary to authorize the URL for the OAuth client on your google project page.

```
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES,
      ux_mode: 'redirect',
      //redirect_uri: custom url to redirect'
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
  }
```

Comment: ux_mode for popup is not showing popup.Can you please tell why?

Comment: @SachinHR a popup could also mean a new tab or it has been blocked by the browser. The default behavior is to open a popup https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs

Comment: If I had asked this question, then I would have accepted yours as a best answer! :)

Comment: THIS SHOULD BE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER! Here is a link to the google documentation that explains the available parameters https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

Comment: this looks appropriate way for inapp webviews. google sign in API with popup has issues with webview when popup tries to close itself and return callback to original window.